# is Firebase Dynamic Links Library Optional?

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

is importing `com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:` optional if my objective is solely reading the deeplink Url? Because for normal deeplink, I can read it directly in activity using `intent.data`. So what extra does `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()` offer here?

Also, how exactly is the deeplink gets pass back to the app for new user who got routed to playstore for installation prior to my app launching?

Could it be:

- firebase store the deeplink/arguments in server and `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()` retrieve back from the server. (this means it will only work when there's internet connectivity)
- via `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast? (sounds very unlikely)
- via launch intent when user press on the "open" button in PlayStore. (but what if the user closes the playstore and launches it from launcher instead? will he still be getting the deeplink?)

### Update

- I'm slowly getting the hang of it. I'm presuming how Firebase does it is by "writing" to the PlayStore app local database when user triggers the link. And after the app is installed, the Firebase library in our app retrieves the value using some ContentProvider patterns.
- Let's say the dynamic link is shared via Whatsapp. The user then opens the link via web.whatsapp.com in their PC chrome browser and proceed to install the app to their selected phone. Question: will the phone receive the dynamic link?